# jQuery Flot plugin version 0.7's line fill property causes invalid chart results

Tags: jquery, flot

I used jquery flot v0.6  in a webpage earlier and it works properly but this version is not compatible with IE 9. So I upgraded the libraries to version 0.7 but "line fill property" does not work and causes the invalid results.

```
 datasets = {
            "total": {
                label: "total",
                data:total,
                *lines: { show:true,fill:true },*
                color:"rgb(255, 128,0)"

            }
            }
```

chart preview in v0.6:

[image: it works properly]

and problem is like this in v0.7 (using the same data):

[image: it shows straight line when fill:true]

however when I set fill:false it works pretty well, but I want to fill the space under the curve[image: fill:false]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually with the scale, not the fill itself.  In 0.7 Flot always fills from zero.  Since your data is so closely-spaced (~26850 to 26920) this ends up looking like a straight line.

Unfortunately there's no easy solution.  In 0.7, your only real choice is to iterate over your data to manually calculate a minimum, and set that as the minimum of the plot.

Looking further ahead, there's a change about to be merged into the master branch that will restore the old functionality and provide an option to toggle between zero or automatic minimum.